# z-index and translateZ relation

Tags: css, dom, safari, z-index

I have 2 absolute positioned divs.
A is on top of B (based on dom order, but this could also be done with z-index).

Inside A, there are multiple of divs, with a z order, based on translateZ (because I want to have the perspective, and I am rotating the divs - with rotateX, etc).
I want to have to topdiv have translateZ: 0, so the other div need to have a negative translateZ (I want to do this, to keep the topdiv sharp), they also have a translateX and translateY, so it looks like a stack.

All divs need to be visible. In Firefox and Chrome, this works, but in Safari, everything with a negative tranlsateZ, falls under the normal (div B) elements, so becomes invisible.
And for the sharp reasons, I don't want to give B a negative translateZ.

live prototype: http://projects.innouveau.com/ventu/2.0/application.html
(B = google maps, divs in A are the cards, which you can drag, to see the rotation)